# Django: Creating endpoint for fetching subcategories within a category

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django and wanted to create an endpoint that allows me to push all the existing subcategories within a category. I have seen methods where one can fetch specific data points within a given category but I am confused about how to create such custom endpoints.

Here's my Serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'categoryType')

class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    categoryTitle = serializers.CharField(source="categoryType.categoryType", read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = SubCategory
        fields = ('id', 'categoryTitle', 'subcategoryType')
        #fields = '__all__'
```

Here's my model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categoryType = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank = False, unique = True, null = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoryType

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    subcategoryType = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    categoryType = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True, related_name='category_type')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.categoryType} :: {self.subcategoryType}'
```

When I hit subcategory endpoint, I get the data in following format:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "categoryTitle": "Electronics",
    "subcategoryType": "Mobile"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "categoryTitle": "Electronics",
    "subcategoryType": "Tablet"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "categoryTitle": "Electronics",
    "subcategoryType": "HardDisk"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "categoryTitle": "Electronics",
    "subcategoryType": "Laptop"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "categoryTitle": "Sports",
    "subcategoryType": "Tennis"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "categoryTitle": "Sports",
    "subcategoryType": "Cricket"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "categoryTitle": "Sports",
    "subcategoryType": "Football"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "categoryTitle": "Sports",
    "subcategoryType": "BasketBall"
  }
]
```

but what I am interested in is getting the data of all the subcategories within a category passing category id in the endpoint:
something like this:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/categories/<categoryId> HTTP/1.1
```

which should return the data in the following way: (Since id 1 belongs to electronics, it should return all the subcategories that fall under electronics category)

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "subcategoryType": "Mobile"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "subcategoryType": "Tablet"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "subcategoryType": "HardDisk"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a nested serializer as below:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subCategories = SubCategorySerializer(source='category_type', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'categoryType', 'subCategories')
```

Please note, you need to mention the related name in source, and have to add `many=True`, as one category can have many subcategories.

Comment: By the method you shared, I am able to make a get request for whole json, but not for a specific category: `GET http://localhost:8000/categories/<categoryId> HTTP/1.1
` like this

Comment: Right! I suppose, you have added the ModelViewSet? Can you share the response of above mentioned endpoint?

Comment: Hi, thanks I was able to do it via `ModelViewSet`. Also I wanted to know if I want to make a post request to create an entry via Model ViewSet then while sending json data in string format it says it expects pk value. Any idea about that?

Comment: For `POST` request, first you need to mention `read_only=True` for nested serializer, as by default create method of serializer doesn't support writable nested serializer. If you would like to make it writable, you will have to customize create method.

Comment: Regarding PK value error, can you share corresponding endpoint definition and view?

Comment: Hey thanks, I sorted it using passing the id. I believe it allows to create a post request only by passing IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `subcategory_set field`.

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'categoryType', 'subcategory_set')
```

This will give you one more field in the output, that is subcategory_set. This will be a list, containing all the subcategory ID.

If you want complete data, use `depth` option

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'categoryType', 'subcategory_set')
        depth = 1
```

Reference : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: It gives me an error saying: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `subcategory_set` is not valid for model `Category`.

Comment: Thanks, I sorted it out via the other method suggested in the answer, not sure where it went wrong.